# Problem with including jsp in another jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I would like create a navigation with URL like Authentification, subscribe, disconnect, etc...
i hava a page with data.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


<html>
    <head>
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
        <jsp:include page="include/header.jsp"></jsp:include><br>
        <jsp:include page="navBarMenu.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <jsp:include page="rechercheSite.jsp"></jsp:include><br>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="navbarSites">
            <p><a href="<c:url value="/formSite"></c:url>">Ajouter un site </a> </p>
        </div>

                <table border="1" id="tableauSites">
                    <caption>Site</caption>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>nom</th>
                        <th>Departement</th>
                        <th>Pays</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Cotation-min</th>
                        <th>Cotation-max</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>

                    <!-- Si aucun critères n'est insérer, on affiche tout les sites -->
                    <!-- Sinon on affiche les sites selon les critères -->

                    <c:forEach var="sites" items="${sites}">
                        <tr>
                                <td><c:out value="${sites.id}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${sites.nom}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${sites.departement}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${sites.pays}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${sites.type}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${sites.cotationMin}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${sites.cotationMax}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${sites.description}"/></td>
                            <td><a href="<c:url value="site/${sites.id}"></c:url>">Gestion du site </a></td>
                            <td><a href="<c:url value="/site/${site.id}/delete"/>">Supprimer le site</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>

                </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Following is the navBarMenu.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>

    <%--    Menu de navigation --%>
    <div class="navbar">
<%--        <%=request.getSession().getAttribute("utilisateur")%>--%>

        <c:if test="${empty sessionScope.pseudo}">

            <p><a href="<c:url value="/sites"></c:url>">Tout les sites</a></p>
            <p><a href="<c:url value="/utilisateurs"></c:url>">Gestion des utilisateurs</a></p>
            <p><a href="<c:url value="/loginUtilisateur"></c:url>">S'authentifier</a></p>

        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${not empty sessionScope.pseudo}">

            <p><a href="<c:url value="/sites"></c:url>">Tout les sites</a></p>
            <p><a href="<c:url value="/utilisateurs"></c:url>">Gestion des utilisateurs</a></p>
<%--            <p><a href="<c:url value="/loginUtilisateur"></c:url>">S'authentifier</a></p>--%>

        </c:if>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

When I copy my navigation menu in my first jsp page it works fine but when I create a separete JSP page and include it in first then it doesn't work.
Menus do not appear at all, neither
I appreciate your help

Comment: You are going to get a lot better help by describing the problem in more detail than "it doesn't work". For us that could mean anything from a display feature not being placed correctly to a total server crash.

Comment: But one thing I do see is that you include all html tags in your included jsp as well as in the parent jsp. That way the result jsp will have all the html elements from your menu jsp inside the head element of the parent jsp. The end result will not be a well formed html, which may cause you issues.

Comment: Ho sorry, It does not fit into any "if", it does not display the menu, neither.

Comment: Include any information related to the question in the question itself by editing the question. It is easier to find rather than having it in comments.

Comment: Can you please check if your paths are correct and relative OR both pages are in same directory? I can not see any other issue if same code is running inline.

Comment: i have just navigation menu which is not displayed. i try with <p>toto</p>